# sed regex for capture group between delimeters

Tags: linux, shell-script, command-line, sed, regular-expression

I have a two line file that I'm trying to get some info out of for a bash script using sed.

```
# File Comment
PrefixForInformation {information to be captured}
```

I need to get the information between but not including the curly braces. 
I have the PCRE regex `/{(.*)}/` or `\s{([^}]*)` that seems to work in [Online Regex 101](https://regex101.com/#pcre) but I can't get that over to a working sed configuration.

Comment: whats wrong with the goat?

Comment: [IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0092086/quotes?item=qt0400529)

Comment: Tried `sed -n 's/{\(.*\)}/\1/p'` but that gets me everything except the braces, including the Prefix and I don't need that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ sed -n 's/.*{\(.*\)}.*/\1/p' file
information to be captured
```

#### How it works

- `-n`

  This tells sed not to print anything unless we explicitly ask it to.
- `s/.*{\(.*\)}.*/\1/p`

  This substitute command captures as group 1 everything between two curly braces.  The whole line is replaced with group 1, denoted `\1`.  The `p` at the end tells sed that, if a match was made, it should print the result.

Comment: Any suggestions for why the anonymous downvote?

Comment: I tried to upvote, but I still only have 13 rep. I was wondering about that downvote?

Comment: @John1024, dunno. it happens sometimes.  its a good answer so here's a +1 from me.